# How can you confirm that two variables are canonically conjugate using Poisson brackets?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets, canonical-conjugation

Suppose you have two conjugate variables $q$ and $p$ that are canonically transformed into two other variables $Q$ and $P$. What needs to hold true for these variables in terms of Poisson brackets? I am being asked to confirm that $Q$ and $P$ are canonically conjugate through Poisson brackets.

Comment: Canonically transformed in what sense?

Answer (score 0):

A canonical trasformation conserve the poisson braket, so if the variables q,p are conjugate they satisfy {p,q} = 1 , also the trasformed variables have to satisfy the same condition

Comment: But isn't that always the case? If you have {Q,P}=(dQ/dQ)*(dP/dP)-(dQ/dP)*(dP/dQ)=1 isnt that always one? I feel like I need to use the relations between the old and new variables.

Comment: If you make a canonical trasformation is always true. But It's not true for a general trasformation.